# How to use select and where clause in sqlite Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have the following code. How do I get a particular value from the list using select ?
Like if I want to use `select * from table_name where Name=Sam;` and get the result value in a string.

How do I do it in SQLITE based on following example?

```
package com.example.sqlitedemo;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


LinearLayout Linear;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
private static String DBNAME = "PERSONS.db";    // THIS IS THE SQLITE      
DATABASE FILE NAME.
private static String TABLE = "MY_TABLE";       // THIS IS <span id="IL_AD9" class="IL_AD">THE TABLE</span> NAME
TextView textView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creating table.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    dropTable();        // DROPPING THE TABLE.
    createTable();

    insertIntoTable();
    selectTable();

}
public void showTableValues(){
    try{
        int rowid=1;
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

       // Cursor allrows  = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);
    }
    finally{

    }
}
// CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
public void createTable(){
    try{
    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, PLACE TEXT);");
    mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
// THIS FUNCTION INSERTS DATA TO THE DATABASE
public void insertIntoTable(){
    try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('CODERZHEAVEN','GREAT INDIA')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('ANTHONY','USA')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('SHUING','JAPAN')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('JAMES','INDIA')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('SOORYA','INDIA')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('MALIK','INDIA')");
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(NAME, PLACE) VALUES('myname','America')");
        mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in inserting into table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
public void selectTable(){
    try{
    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from TABLE where NAME=JAMES", null);

    String name = c.getString(0);
    String place = c.getString(1);
    textView1.setText(name);
    mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error selecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

}

public void dropTable(){
    try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydb.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE);

        mydb.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered while dropping.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `mydb`

```
Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from MY_TABLE where NAME=MALIK");
String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
String place = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PLACE"));
```

Now you have access to your two columns `Name` and `Place` to do as you please as according to the data you have provided from your code snippet.

Comment: I added your code but it gives me error it says: 04-04 07:54:05.215: E/SQLiteLog(3037): (1) no such column: JAMES ! Please help thankyou :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick Reply but it says"The method getString(int) in the type Cursor is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: Updated again, I was doing it from memory and made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

```
    //Cursor cursorr = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
```

Cursor cursorr =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE_EHS + " where " + TASK_ID + "='" + taskid + "'" , null);

```
    if (cursorr.moveToFirst()) 
   {

        do {

            // your code like get columns

            }
         while (cursorr.moveToNext());
    }
}
```